# Store and retrieve data table into Varbinary column

Tags: sql-server, datatable, grid, store, varbinary

For some reason I had to store a DataTable variable in a `Varbinary` column of a SQL Server table, but I get errors.

This is store code:

```
// Read DataTable to Byte array
DataTable dtgrd = new DataTable();
DataAccess ds = new DataAccess();
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
dst.Tables.Add(dtgrd);

string xmlString = dst.GetXml();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
xml.Save(ms);

byte[] xmlBytes = ms.ToArray();

// Store DataTable into database
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(Global.cs);
string str = @"INSERT INTO...... ";

SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(str, CN);
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FKDocInReqID", FKDocInReqID));
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", (object)xmlBytes));
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", ReportTitle));
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocUploadUser_secuserID", Global.S_UserID));

CN.Open();
decimal id =(decimal) SqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
CN.Close();
```

The store code has worked correctly and in the database, the columns has the proper bytes.

But the retrieve code does not work:

```
 string s = @"select * from .... where id={0} ";
 s = string.Format(s, id);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = ds.doSelect(s);

 using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Value"]))
 {
     dataGridView1.DataSource = FromBytes(memStream1.ToArray());
     dataGridView1.Refresh();
     dataGridView1.Show();
 }
```

and

```
static DataTable FromBytes(byte[] arr)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        {
            return (DataTable)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);//**ERROR Raised Here**
        }
    }
static byte[] ToBytes(DataTable table)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            table.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, table);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

this error is raised:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quBWL.png)

Comment: How do you get memStream1's bytes back into xmlBytes?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: ok bro now what is your point about that error?

Comment: 1) Please don't call me "bro" 2) Post your error as text not as an image.

Comment: this is error text:System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 3C-4E-65-77-44-61-74-61-53-65-74-3E-0D-0A-20-20-3C ...'

Answer (score 0):

The [example code on Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.getxml?view=net-5.0#examples) uses `XmlTextReader`

```cs
static DataTable FromBytes(Stream st)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(st))
    {  
        ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
    }
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

I'll leave you to think about the obvious design flaws in storing one table *within* another.

Comment: this code has error in last line :System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find table 0.'

Comment: For some reason didn't work with `ReadSchema`, should work now

Answer (score 0):

this is how I figure out this problem maybe help to someone else.
instead of save data into Varbinary field save it to xml in nvarchar(max) and then retrieve it :

```
//Retrieve Process:
string s = @"select * from .... where id={0} ";
s = string.Format(s, ID);
DataTable dtlist = new DataTable();
DataAccess ds = new DataAccess();
dtlist = ds.doSelect(s);//doselect is function that run select sql command

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(dtlist.Rows[0]["Data"].ToString());//data is column name that store xml in it
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(xml.InnerXml);
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

gridEX1.DataSource = theDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: You should really save XML in an `xml` type column. But in this case, you would be better off with a completely separate table